# Filemaker Getting Record ID from Related Value in Calculated Repeating Field

Tags: filemaker

I am working on an image gallery.  Horizontal portals were not an option here.  I Have created a nice thumbnail grid using a vertical portal and a repeating field.

I used GetNth to grab the images.

GetNthRecord ( Extend(FARMS_PHOTOS 2::IMAGE) ; Get ( CalculationRepetitionNumber ) )

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the image ID for each image into a script.  I want this to function like a traditional image gallery.  So the idea is to now attach a script to the repeating field that will grab the Image ID so that it can be manipulated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k there is a method for building horizontal portals that is commonly used by Filemaker developers for photo grids.  No it is not a native FMP portal (I was hoping that they would address that in FMP 13).  See examples here. http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/90092e94b2.  I have never been a fan of it because it isn't polished enough for me.  It has UI limitations because of Filemaker's auto-sizing limitations. I am trying to develop a slick full-screen design so I have modified a piece of code that I have used in the past for calendars.  Do you have any input on the script?

Comment: Are you referring to the demo posted by "comment" on FMForums?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, the username is next to the word "comment" in FMforums.  There are 2 zips in that thread but it's the same concept.  I've seen the same solution all over the web for building a photo grid and really nothing else out there.  It doesn't work for this design because the autosizing is garbage.  I want a nice tight grid like the Facebook photo grid that is perfectly spaced.  But I have already built the grid.  I am looking for a script here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches to this problem.

**Option 1. Use a Script Parameter to tell the script what repeat is being clicked.**

You will need break up the repeating field into individual field objects for each repeat. You can do this by setting the "show repeat" option on the "Data" of the inspector. When you do that each field object and therefor repeat can be it's own button.  Each button can get its own parameter.  So you assign a parameter of 1 to the field object for repeat 1 and so on. Now that you have a script parameter for each repeat you can use a variation of the GetNthRecord calc you showed above to get the ID

This is a bit tedious to setup but it behaves well.

**Option 2. Use an ObjectEnter Script Trigger**

If you don't want to break up the repeating field object you can instead attach an object script trigger to the repeating field.  Pass in "Get ( ActiveRepetitionNumber )" as the script parameter. When the user clicks into the field the script will fire and receive the repetition number as the Script Parameter. Then proceed with your GetNthRecord calc.

This is easier to setup. But the event that triggers the script is a Mouse Down event. That's a bit weird. Buttons should fire on Mouse Up, not Mouse Down.  Also you will have to tweak the styles so that it doesn't look weird when the user enters into that field. But it works

Comment: Todd Geist!  I've been reading your Filemaker articles for years!  It's great that you are in here!  I'm trying this now.  I think option #1 is the answer.

Comment: Wait no it has to be option#2 because of the UI.  I want to keep the clean spacing that the single object provides.  Trying it now.

Comment: Hi @toddgeist, the grid portal is in the bottom right hand corner of the screen inside of a tabset that is set to resize in all directions.  I need the grid to stretch to fullscreen evenly and fit the margins/line up perfectly with all other page elements.  I would def prefer the button but I didn't think it was possible.  Am I missing something with auto-sizing here?  Is it possible to place 7 fields in a portal and have them all resize evenly and stretch to the full width of the portal to create the appearance of a responsive design (not just centered)?  I've never been able to achieve that.

Comment: If you want the thing to resize in a somewhat responsive manner then you will need to use option 2. glad you like my blog :-)